# Pairwise Comparison with Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have a large text file (5 GB) with one string per line.  I need to compare each line to every other line using a proprietary algorithm.  I'm new to MapReduce, but have Java experience.  the issue that is giving me trouble is creating the separate map inputs.  Documentation seems to be written with the assumption that each line isn't dependent on any other line.  What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: It doesn't look like it will fit into M-R paradigm. One suggestion - produce pairs <string1, string2> without M-R and run M-R on these pairs?

Comment: That's a possibility, but it seems a little hackish to take a 5GB file and make it 25GB just for the sake of getting around a coding problem.

Comment: Can you provide 5G of memory on each task? Otherwise you have to read the file fully for every line in the file. Which is possible, but very likely to be slow and error prune.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some interesting papers on doing joins with Hadoop:

http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM100859.pdf
http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/publications/thesis/online/IM090720.pdf
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jignesh/publ/hadoopjoin.pdf

I think you should also look into the Hadoop mapred join framework:

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/join/package-summary.html